# Splitting field of a polynomial in an extension of degree 2 in characteristic 2

Tags: field-theory

Let $K \subset L$ be an extension of degree 2. If $\operatorname{char}(K)=2$ then there exists $a \in K$ such that $L$ is the splitting field over $K$ of a polynomial of the form $X^2-a$ or $X^2-X-a$.

My attempt, Since the extension is of degree 2, $L=K(\alpha)$ and the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ over $K$ has the form $X^2+bX+c$ Now if $b=0$ the result follows, how to show the other part?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You know $\alpha$ is a root of $X^{2} + b X + c$, with $b \ne 0$. Write $\alpha = d \gamma$, with $d \in K$, and determine a monic polynomial $f$  in $K[X]$ of degree $2$ of which $\gamma$ is a root. Choosing an appropriate $d$, can you make the coefficient of $X$ in $f$ equal $1$?

Comment: what is $\gamma$? can you please elaborate it a little more.

Comment: Simply, choose any $d \in K^{\star}$, and take $\gamma = d^{-1} \alpha$. Now substitute $\alpha = d \gamma$ in $X^2 + b X + c$.

Comment: Well, I am sorry but i just don't understand why $\alpha=d \gamma$ and if it is a root then the monic polynomial for which $\gamma$ is a root is $X^2+bd^{-1}X+cd^{-1}$

Comment: @WaqasAliAzhar You're there! Just choose $d = -b^{-1}$, write $a = - cd^{-1} = c b$, and note that $L = K(\alpha) = K(\gamma)$.

Comment: I appreciate alot your help, but please what I am missing here is why exactly $\alpha=d \gamma$ where $d \in K$

Comment: @WaqasAliAzhar, it's just a substitution, to get from the polynomial $X^2 + bX + c$, with $b \ne 0$, to a polynomial of the required form $X^2 - X - a$. You have probably seen similar substitutions in the form $X \mapsto u X + v$ to get from one polynomial to another.